# SettingWithCopyWarning even when using .copy

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm using pandas 1.5.0, and I'm getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning`, for the following code:

```
    df["data"] = df["data"].apply(clip_from_start, args=(16,))
    df = df.dropna()
    df[aug1_col] = df[column].map(augmentor).copy()
    df[aug2_col] = df[column].map(augmentor).copy()
```

The other reference on this topic: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) seems to indicate that using `.copy` should solve the trick. But, it isn't working here.

I also tried:

```
        df.loc[:, aug1_col] = df[column].apply(augmentor)
        df.loc[:, aug2_col] = df[column].apply(augmentor)
```

but that didn't work either.

Is the warning in this case just bogus, or is it doing something useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to do:

```
    df["data"] = df["data"].apply(clip_from_start, args=(16,))
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.copy()
    df[aug1_col] = df[column].map(augmentor).copy()
    df[aug2_col] = df[column].map(augmentor).copy()
```